# unexpected android system call makes smooth display of scrolling graphic stutter

Tags: android, graphics, scroll, system, real-time

I am currently writing an app that should display a real time measurement curve in a scrolling fashion (think ECG recorder or oscilloscope). An unexpected system call in the UI-Thread makes the display stutter.

The data rolls in via bluetooth. All works fine and the display is reasonably smoothly scrolling with an average update rate of 26 frames/s. But, nevertheless the display is stuttering remarkably.

I used traceview to get more insight and according to traceview the stuttering is the result of a call to `android/view/ViewRoot.handleMessage` which lasts 131 ms per call on average.
If I dig down further in traceview the cycles are burnt inside `android/view/ViewRoot.performTraversals`. 92% of these CPU cycles are consumed in mostly recursive calls to `android/view/View.measure`.

From there it gets complicated due to the recursive call structure. But I can find calls to the onMeasure() method of LinearLayout, FrameLayout and RelativeLayout. The onMeasure() method of each Layout type consumes about the same amount of CPU cycles. Which is very strange since in my activity I use only a simple LinearLayout with just 2 Elements. 
I just see no reason on why a supposed re-layout of a LinearLayout with 2 Elements performs calls to non-used Layouts and takes a whopping 131 ms to do that.

Further info:

- Platform HTC desire HD with Android 2.3.1.
- I use a handler to perform the drawing in the UI thread.
- The Layout is a simple LinearLayout with 2 Elements: a custom view and a textField.
- The status bar is hidden with `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`.
- The drawing is performed on each new block of data, which arrives approx. every 50 ms.
- The drawing itself uses a canvas and is performant enough to keep up with the incoming data.

After that long explanation, here are the questions:

1. What is calling the android/view/ViewRoot.handleMessage? (the calls are relatively equal spaced every 850 ms and have no obvious link (no direct calls, number of calls and relative positions are not linked to the message handler for drawing) to any activity of my Activity)
2. How can I suppress the calls to android/view/ViewRoot.handleMessage or how can I make them faster (there are just 2 elements in my LinearLayout)
3. the calls to unused layouts first got me think of the status bar or some hidden activity (e.g. home screen), which may use such layouts. But how come those calls are part of the trace of my activity? As far as I understand the trace should only trace the active process. e.g. the calls of my service which produces the real time data is not part of the trace.
4. Is there any possibility to trace individual calls to some system components? When I zoom in in traceview I see this call sequence: `toplevel -> android/os/Message.clearForRecycle() -> android/os/MessageQueue.nativePollOnce() -> android/os/SystemClock.uptimeMillis() -> com/htc/profileflag/ProfileConfig.getProfilePerformance() -> android/os/Handler.dispatchMessage() ->  android/view/ViewRoot.performTraversals()`
5. Off topic: Is there a possibility to export the data which is shown inside traceview (parents-children-CPU time etc.) other than a screenshot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I found the reason for the long call to `android/view/ViewRoot.handleMessage`.
This was indeed caused by my application.

My App has 2 screens (Activities) one with a complicated Layout for status information and the other one the real time display of incoming data.

The data, which comes in over bluetooth contains mixed real time data and status data. When I switch to the real time Activity, I was stopping the status Activity with `finish();` after starting the new real time Activity. Unfortunately this is not enough to stop also the message handler, which receives the new status information in the UI thread, and continued to update status data in an invisible and finished Activity. The relayout of this activity caused the stutter of the real time data.

This is now solved. The display scrolling is now reasonable smooth.

Thanks for your patience. May it be useful to anyone who stumbles on this Thread on stackoverflow.

jepo